# Java animated GIF and MySQL connection

Tags: java, mysql, swing, gif, freeze

I a making a Java Messenger. I did a login dialog and when I click on the connect button, an animated GIF appears while it's loading.

The problem is that the animated GIF stops moving while my MySQL connection and Query are processing.

I throw the MySQL connection and query in a new thread but still the same :

```
Thread connectionThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        //Database conection
                        OlaDB.createConnection();
...
```

What can I do to avoid my GIF freezing ?

Answer (score 6):

> When a Swing program needs to execute a long-running task, it usually uses one of the *worker threads*, also known as the *background threads*.

Have a look at  [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)  and [Using a Swing Worker Thread.](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html)

also Read up on on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on why the GUI freezes and for a working example of using a Swing Worker. (via @camickr)

Comment: +1, Read up on on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on  why the GUI freezes and for a working example of using a Swing Worker.